# error with :maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-plugin

Trying to run a program with maven and keep getting this error any ideas on how to fix? ps- I'm a complete newbie with maven/tomcat/springframework etc

```
ebitnami@ubuntu:~$ cd OpenESPI-Common-java/
bitnami@ubuntu:~/OpenESPI-Common-java$ mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Common 1.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean- 
plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.809s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 17 16:21:44 EDT 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not 
 be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean- 
 plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 
 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: 
 http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean- 
 plugin-2.5.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following 
 articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: The access to central repository is https only. I assume you are using an old Maven version. Can you please check which one via `mvn --version`?

Comment: yes it  is Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-170-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: Ok...very old version of Maven...please upgrade to most recent Maven version (3.6.3) and if you use Java 7 you have to use `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`... See https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required